# HTML span contents stay on the same row

Tags: html, css

Okay. So I have a div full of spans and every span has a word or a few inside. The div fits multiple rows and has a fixed width. I need the span contents to stay same on the same row, not to break so that one word in a span is on the first and the rest of the words on the next one.

Let me give you a small example.

HTML

```
<div>
    <span>Hamburgers</span> 
    <span>Pizza and hotdogs</span>
    <span>Milk and beer</span>
    <span>Kids menu</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    text-align:center;
    width:400px;
}
span{
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

Now the result I'm looking for is something like this:

```
   Hamburgers      Pizza and hotdogs
     Milk and beer     Kids menu
```

But what might happen is this:

```
   Hamburgers      Pizza and hotdogs    Milk
           and beer     Kids menu
```

I tried setting `white-space: no-wrap` but that just set everthing on one row. I have a feeling that using the `white-space: no-wrap` the right way is the key, but I haven't got to it yet.

I hope you get the point what I'm trying to achieve and where I am now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`white-space: nowrap;` will prevent any type of line wrapping. It sounds like you want to use non-breaking spaces `&nbsp;` in your titles, which will prevent the phrases from wrapping in the middle. For example:

```
<div>
    <span>Hamburgers</span> 
    <span>Pizza&nbsp;and&nbsp;hotdogs</span>
    <span>Milk&nbsp;and&nbsp;beer</span>
    <span>Kids&nbsp;menu</span>
</div>
```

Note: the `&nbsp;` is called an HTML entity. It will render just like a regular space character to the end-user, but it tells the browser to not allow words to be broken into multiple lines.

Comment: That indeed was the correct answer, I can't accept it yet. And a little notice here also, I used PHP to create the span elements. Used `str_replace()` to replace regular spaces with non-breaking ones and had to put an extra space after the span closing tag so the line could break from there.

Answer (score 0):

See this reference: [W3CSchools white-space reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

You can apply `white-space: pre` to your spans using css. This will allow them to wrap on line-breaking white-space characters, but not other white-space characters.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
span {
  margin-right: 10px;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hamburgers</span> 
  <span>Pizza and hotdogs</span>
  <span>Milk and beer</span>
  <span>Kids menu</span>
</div>
```